# mPDF 5.7.1 - image displays as a broken [x]

Tags: php, html, image, mpdf

I have a small issue with mPDF (version 5.7.1).

This code should generate PDF with image file:

```
 $mpdf = new mPDF();
 $html = '<img src="https://www.google.pl/images/srpr/logo11w.png"/>';
 $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
 $mpdf->debug = true; 
 $output = $mpdf->Output(); 
 exit();
```

Well there is no image but an `[x]` instead.

I've googled enough to get to the conclusion that it has to be done this way but I also tried realpath to the file. Still nothing.

The only thing I haven't tried is `<img src="logo11w.png">` and copying the image into the folder because I don't know into which folder I should copy file `logo11w.png`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: mPDF will automatically download the resources which are external. Maybe try writing the PDF to disk: $mpdf->Output(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'test.pdf', 'F');

Comment: Good idea, but not good enough... :( Still nothing.

Comment: Try Relative URLS. It worked for me

Comment: My images were served that required the user to be logged on; curl wasn't and I had forgotten it also needed to be, wondering why the script got 404s while my browser showed the images just fine.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

I had the same problem with PNG images being displayed as [X] when to generate PDFs with mPDF.

I added: `$mpdf->showImageErrors = true;`

After: `$mpdf = new Mpdf();`

and got the error message:

> GD library required for PNG image (alpha channel)#

So after running `apt-get install php5-gd` generating a PDF with a PNG worked like a charm!

Comment: Have to accept Your question. I won't be able to check the results but still helped me on a very similar issue on mpdf v6.0. 
That's weird that debug = true  doesn't show what showImageErrors = true does.
Thanks for Your help.

Comment: This was really helpful. I ran `yum install php56w-gd` and restarted my web service and that did the trick. If you use yum, it might be `yum install php-gd` as well.

Comment: This solution worked for me. For PHP 7.0 the command is `sudo apt-get install php7.0-gd`

Comment: I can still see any errors after adding `$mpdf->showImageErrors = true;`. Any help ? I have GD library  installed too

Comment: This is how someone should response to questions on stackoverflow

Answer (score 25):

Including images is kinda tricky in mPDF. I had some issues as well. I found more kind of problems.

At first you should turn on debug variable:

```
$mpdf = new mPDF();    
$mpdf->showImageErrors = true;
```

Usualy people don't have installed GD module for PHP. On linux machine, execute:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-gd
sudo service apache2 restart
```

On Windows servers, php_gd2.dll is included in a standard PHP installation, but is not enabled by default. To enable it, uncomment the *extension=php_gd2.dll* line in your *php.ini* file (remove the # from the beginning of that line) and restart the PHP extension. [[1](https://shopplugin.net/kb/installing-the-gd-library-for-php/)]

If you get this error you probably see [x] image:

> mPDF error: IMAGE Error (http://www.domain.com/directory/image.jpg): Could
>   not find image file

Check the url if your image exists and if the image is accessible. If yes then you can try to change absolute URL to relative. You can try both versions:

```
<img src="directory/image.jpg">
<img src="./directory/image.jpg">
```

Actually I also had a problem with PNG formats. Converted PNG image to JPG worked fine.

Linking in mPDF templates should be same like for whole your framework/system.

Answer (score 18):

I have encountered the same problem after migrating the script.

The problem was, that the `tmp` directory inside the mpdf folder was not writable. I hope it helps someone.

Comment: Buddy, you are a genius, you just saved my butt ^_º (upvoted +1!).

Comment: You are the boss. You save my day. Bunch Of Flowers for you.

Comment: plus plus for you buddy

Answer (score 5):

For me, it is working as of now. Hope this will help someone.

**Solution : Try relative path of image instead of URL. Image must be hosted on the same server.**

Ex: /var/www/mysite/image/xyz.jpg

Comment: That did the trick for me

Answer (score 2):

In my project i fix problem and solution is:

Set src absolute path on the server example: 
`src="/var/www/myproject/images/logo.png"` if image is on the same server. 
If image is from external server src is absolute path example:
`src="https://www.google.bg/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"`.
Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 2):

Just experienced this issue today with an old website.

If you have mPDF <= 6.0 and you are now experiencing this issue when it was previously working. The reason is that there is an SSL error (expired certificate, invalid certificate, etc). The solution is the fix the SSL certificate installation; however, if you want a quick fix you can edit the mpdf.php file to ignore SSL errors during CURL requests.  Simply add:

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);`

Inside the functions:

`file_get_contents_by_curl`

and

`_get_file`

Answer (score 1):

Ok. After the last comment on question (14:30). Here the exact same code that IS working with mPDF 5.4. And it saves it's output on scripts directory as test.pdf. Firewall issues?

**Edited**

I have the following directories / files:

- images

  - wallpaper01.jpg
  - wallpaper02.jpg
- index.php (source code)

So these image files are relatively starting from the script directory as it looks like.

```
require_once __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'MPDF/mpdf.php';

try {
    $mpdf = new mPDF(); 
    $mpdf->WriteHTML('<img src="images/wallpaper01.jpg" alt="" width="480">');
    $mpdf->WriteHTML('<img src="images/wallpaper02.jpg" alt="" width="480">');
    $mpdf->Output(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'test.pdf', 'F');
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e;
}
```

[Fully working example (download)](https://mega.co.nz/#!uFQgQCIC!gIfOAKKLR4oqFmdZQlg3N029zwKusaaBIvBu_MguB5w)

Comment: I was trying to do so on a local files (my own virtual host domain) so those are not firewall issues for sure.
Tried to downgrade to 5.4 - didn't work as well. Tried changing owner and file mod - nothing.

Comment: Did had time earlier. Made a full working example. Just place it in directory on your server and go.

Comment: * Didn't had time earlier

Comment: I am aware of this fact that it would work from script folder but i am working on a Zend Framework project so i need to have an order in app. Maybe some symbolic link will do the trick - i'm gonna check this but not now. Thanks for your help. If it will work don't be suprised that your reputation will grow. :) :P

Comment: Haha. Good luck! Let us know :)

Answer (score 1):

It's enough
The solve is :

```
$mpdf->curlAllowUnsafeSslRequests = true;
```

It's all

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was just the usage of transparents PNG using the 6.0 version. This bug was fixed on the mpdf 6.1 version.

I successfully solved the problem downloading the 6.1 version from [here](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/releases/tag/v6.1.3) and overriding the mpdf files on my project.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$mpdf->imageVars['myvariable'] = file_get_contents('alpha.png');
```

or

```
$html = '<img src="var:myvariable"/>';
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
```

after there, you should do:

```
$mpdf->Image('var:myvariable', 0, 0);
```

read more about this in documentation:
[mPDF Load Image](https://mpdf.github.io/what-else-can-i-do/images.html)

Answer (score 0):

I am using Code Ignitor and mpdf. After installing php-gd5 library, I had to re-install the php with configure command  --with-gd to resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem using **MPDF 8.1.x** where I could not use URL paths for my images.

Eventually I determined it was caused because the "curlUserAgent" setting was using a very old user agent.

The setting was found here:
**/mpdf/src/Config/ConfigVariables.php**

The curlUserAgent was set to:

```
'curlUserAgent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0.1',
```

But I updated this to:

```
'curlUserAgent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:108.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/108.0',
```

and the images successfully loaded from URL source.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue after we moved our code to AWS Server.

After some debugging, I found the solution. We need to **give write permissions to the mpdf/tmp directory**.

After giving 0777 permission to mpdf/tmp directory, its working for me.

> *We don't need to give write permission to the whole mpdf directory. It may cause security issues.*

[Refer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76462948/6743069)

Comment: Giving any directory in production 0777 is a bad idea. I would suggest checking what user is accessing that directory via PHP or your web server before giving it public write.

Comment: Yes, but for the store temporary images, we should give write permission of the folder. We can create index.html in the directory for preventing unwanted access of the directory

Answer (score 0):

Having this error:

> Could not find image file (http:://localhost:8000/path/of/image)

But image path is correct. Twig code:

```
<img src="{{ asset('/build/path/to/image') }}" />
```

mPDF uses curl to obtain image file, although image are in same server.

The **solution** for me was adding **./** before {{ asset() }} tag.

```
<img src="./{{ asset('/build/path/to/image') }}" />
```

Answer (score -1):

change to
remove the second line before initializing $html
its undefined at that time.
new code will be as

```
$mpdf = new mPDF();
$html= "<img src='https://www.google.pl/images/srpr/logo11w.png' alt=''>";
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->debug = true; 
$output = $mpdf->Output(); 
exit();
```

Comment: Thats not the issue - the $html is initialized before new mPDF();

Comment: then concat the $html string till WriteHTML function call.

Answer (score -1):

Another reason might be you're running your application in Docker (or another container) and you're using a domain that can't be resolved.

Adding an alias in my docker-compose file resolved the issue for me.

```
networks:
  app-network:
    aliases:
      - your.local.domain
```

To find out if this is the reason, log into the running container and attempt to request the file via curl/wget/etc.

Comment: That's exactly the conditions I have. I'm running my Laravel application in a container. Sorry, I'm new in the whole container realm & couldn't tell what you meant, if I can CURL the URL that means it's the reason what you've said or the other way around. Well, I can't CURL my URL and MPDF couldn't as well, however I can CURL outside urls like [this](https://via.placeholder.com/400x150.png?text=Company%20Logo), Any suggestions ? Also, I haven't actually create virtualhost / local_domain instead using 127.0.0.1:8000 and my web app can display the images using those URLs

Answer (score -1):

Had the same issue today. Problem was that the file was in another folder on the same server of the file calling the "save pdf" function.

```
copy("holdpath.bmp","samepath.bmp");
$writer->save("someotherpath.pdf");
unlink("samepath.bmp");
```